# When I go to tools connect to Microsoft azure subscription missing assembly

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015

Hi when I try to open connect to Microsoft Azure Subscription in Visual Studio 2015 RC I get:

An error ocurred during the sign in process: COuld not load file or assembly Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory
Version=2.16.0.0.... or one of its dependencies.

I don't have any project loaded just by clicking that option the error appears. Uninstalled and did clean install, same issue.

Please help...

Comment: Same for me. Clean install of VS 2015 RC Enterprise.. Any solution?

Comment: I ended up installing windows 10 and new Visual Studio 2015. 2015 RC was buggy with Windows 8.